# Few font size-related layout issues

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I am using a default font size of 26px and stackoverflow's layout seems to not work well with such a large sizes.

The most important issue is that many inputs tend to overflow and partially get hidden below side text. This includes one with login, ‘Title’ and — the most important issue — the editor, which makes writing posts a little painful.

Another important one is that sometimes 'search' field doesn't fit in topbar and jumps lower, being partially hidden by logo. I met that issue on stackoverflow itself only while serverfault & meta display fine (but that may be related to rep or sth).

There's one minor issue too — navbar is too narrow and ‘Ask Question’ jumps below — but this one looks quite nice (maybe it's even intended?).

Screenshot: (click to enlarge)

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot link is dead; any chance you could upload the image (or regenerate the problem) and use the handy imgur hosting?

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use browser zoom instead of font scaling?

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001212.html

We only support +1 and -1 font sizes, but browser zoom works (almost) infinitely in either direction.

Comment: Because ‘zoom’ is an ugly workaround. Fluid or not fluid, at least field widths should be fixed.

Comment: How is "zoom" an ugly workaround? It's the only option which reliably scales the entire page up, thereby both making it easier to read and maintaining the designers' original intent.

Comment: Zoom does not work so well with large font sizes. After a few zooming up What I get on firefox 3.6 is a large blank column on the left and less and less space used for actual question titles. This blank column gets wider and wider when I continue zooming. What bother me is that this annoying blank column on the left appears with the (quite large, agreed) font size confortable for me.

Comment: I get the same behavior with zoom as @kriss (with smaller but still larger-than-SE-default fonts, BTW), and had to resort to Stylish and CSS overrides to make the site work with larger fonts.  But I'm not very good with CSS and often bump into problems I don't know how to fix, like overlapping text.  This is text zoom, by the way; whole-page zoom is a lose because you have to scroll horizontally to read anything.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an edge case. I understand that some may use higher font sizes, but there does come a point where a design typically won't scale. This is particularly true of sites like S[OFU], which are not "fluid" designs in the traditional sense.

Technically, yes, it's a bug -- it makes the site harder to use for some users. However, if it were my code, time and effort, I'd probably file it as a very low-prio bug, unless it could be shown to be affecting a non-trivial number of users.