# Sidebar covers text area

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, user-interface, design

Even as I'm writing this post, there is a bug on StackOverflow which prevents me from continuing.  That is, I must open up a text editor on my computer, then cut this text and paste it into the text editor in order to continue writing.

The reason is that the informational sidebar which (is suppose to) appear to the right side of this text area, actually covers the entire right third of the text area.  So I cannot see that part of what I'm typing!

There are a handful of websites on which I have similiar layout issues,  I think it's because of the less common screen resolution and/or DPI settings that I use -- 1680 by 1050 pixels and 125% normal size (120 dpi).  StackOverflow is the only website with this issue that I use regularly.

So I would be very happy if you could address it.  Here's a screen shot - Note that this issue occurs only in Firefox -- I'm running the latest version which is 3.5.3:

[image: width berth on textarea]

Comment: potential privacy issue: your email address is viewable in your screenshot

Comment: Blurred out the email address. But now the miners are trapped.

Comment: It's funny because I can still see your email address in the revision history. Seeing as it is hosted on your Google Pages account, you might want to just delete it and replace it...

Answer (score 6):

> ...1680 by 1050 pixels and **125% normal size** (120 dpi)...

This is your problem - Stack Overflow does not support font scaling, and it's doubtful that it will in the near future. You should try full-page zoom instead - this is the [recommended method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/few-font-size-related-layout-issues/20702#20702) for scaling the site.

Comment: The 125% thing effects all apps, not just Firefox, and isn't the problem.  But font scaling is indeed the culprit.  I have Firefox set to use a minimum font size of 18.  Eliminating that is not a viable option.  Using only full-page zoom makes website graphics way too big, eating up precious vertical space on my laptop's wide-screen monitor.  Plus it makes some text way too big in order to make small text legible.  As much as I love your website, I won't put up with those worse annoyances.  I hope you decide to support font scaling soon.  Text zoom really does have a place in modern browsers.

Comment: If a table was used for layout, putting the textarea in one cell and the side bar in another, this issue wouldn't occur.  I haven't done HTML web design in ten plus years, so maybe I'm just being old-fashioned by suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if a comment has [very long inline math markup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427181/prime-factors-of-numbers-formed-by-primorials), causing the comments to overflow their container (it should have a scrollbar in that situation).