# Layout breakage with larger than normal text/view size

Tags: support, bug

Recently (as in today), the layout of the website (on FireFox 10.0.2) has become broken in places if you use larger than standard sized text. For example, I run with 115% text size (and 140% zoom, but that doesn't affect layout). And here's what I get on a tag page:

[image: SO Broken Layout]

If I reduce it to 110% text size, then it works:

[image]

The thing is, if I shrink it down to 110%, the text is too small. So I'd have to increase the page zoom to 150%, at which point the layout breaks again. Plus, the page becomes too wide to comfortably *read*.

This was working literally yesterday, so I would hope that they could just rollback whatever CSS layout changes broke it.

---

I've found that the layout issue only happens if the `featured` tab is visible. In tags that don't have bountied questions, the layout works fine. I'm guessing it has something to do with the size of the top bar getting too wide, thus forcing weirdness.

Comment: Possibly related: [Few font size-related layout issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/few-font-size-related-layout-issues)

Comment: I use Chrome browser, with 150% page zoom, and 110% text size. I was able to recreate the effect you noticed by clicking on a tag. But even as I zoomed all the way back down to 100%, the layout stayed broken. But I couldn't recreate it when I tried again just now.

Comment: Honestly though, it doesn't bother me. I wouldn't have considered it "broken", although you are correct, probably. (StackExchange is  among the VERY best websites as far as accommodating my vision needs.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page design broken on stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125421/page-design-broken-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: [Another related post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125408/tag-wiki-excerpts-getting-displayed-incorrectly-on-so-with-ff-10)