# Alignment Problem in Mozilla, while showing Tagged Questions?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, design

There is an alignment problem in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services?sort=featured).

Wile watching **tag-info** there is no problem, but for other views alignment was gone in **Mozilla Firefox**(as shown in below image).

[image]

It's working fine in `IE 8`.

But this problem is not there in [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=featured&pagesize=15).(see below image).

[image]

is this is a known Issue?

Comment: Hey, I had the same issue today too. I just opened a question, but deleted it as someone pointed out to this question. I was able to reproduce it with the tags: google-app-engine, azure, cloudfoundry.

Comment: Perhaps the same issue as [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125421/page-design-broken-on-stackoverflow) and/or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125408/tag-wiki-excerpts-getting-displayed-incorrectly-on-so-with-ff-10)?

Comment: [There's advertisement which seems to break the layout.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9IB8O.png)

Comment: Azad uses `It's working fine in IE 8`.  ***Its super effective!***

Comment: It would be good to tell us your FF version. `Help/About Firefox`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh Firefox - why are you not chrome?   A fix will be deployed shortly.

Comment: Yes, isn't it about time that Mozilla gave up that Gecko thing and started using jQuery^H^H^H^H^H^H WebKit?