# Website is not formatted correctly

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alignment Problem in Mozilla, while showing Tagged Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125743/alignment-problem-in-mozilla-while-showing-tagged-questions)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8 -> layout is messed-up

[image]

Firefox 11 under windows 7